# Show only active records in lookup - CRM

Tags: dynamics-crm, crm

I have custom entity which has lookup to the Products entity record.

I want this field to show only active(status) Products.

How can I do this? am I supposed to make new lookup view in Products, change existing one, or something else?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should pick the view you'd like to render the records from. Navigate to form customizations, and edit the field property to look like below:

[image]